# Local user account created with Powershell is NOT shown in settings "Family & Other people"

Tags: windows, powershell, kiosk-mode, windows-10-desktop, superuser

I am working on Windows 10 Assigned Access for Desktop for version 1607.

**Mission:** I need to get Assigned Access to work with Powershell.

**Steps done:**
I create a new LocalUser account with New-LocalUser and I enable the account with Enable-LocalUser. To check if the account is added, I run Get-LocalUser and see that the account is created (see attachment).

**Issue:** 
To double check I go to the PC settings for Accounts-Family & other people, but I cannot see the new local user account "KioskTest".

I have restarted the computer but the account is not added to "Family & Other people".

I have spent some time on this and I would really appreciate your help,  **How can I make sure that the added Local user "KioskTest" is shown in the PC Accounts settings-Family & other people, when using Powershell?**

I can Set-AssignedAccess, when I do Get-AssignedAccess I can see that it is there. Trouble is, I cannot login to the local user account because I cannot find the account in the settings for the PC.

It's like powershell has "hidden" the local user account from my client computer!!!

**ADDED information + updated images:**
After some trial and error I found out the following:

- Using NET USER username password/ADD --works perfectly! I can find the user account and login as a customer would. The account is part of the LocalGroupMember
- The local user account created with New-LocalUser with Powershell does NOT appear in the PC account settings BUT if you click on set assigned access in the Family & other people the system finds the local user account (see attachment). However you cannot login to the account as it seemingly does not have a group membership! Not great for testing :(

Thanks for taking the time,
Karina

See attachment:
[Powershell Get-AssignedAccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ2FC.jpg)
[PC Account settings Family & other people](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7eyg.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you [use PowerShell to set assigned access?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions) Here's the [TechNet article on Set-AssignedAccess](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn336440.aspx)

Comment: Sure thing, I can Set-AssignedAccess! But most important, how can I login to the local user account to test Assigned Access as the account is not showing up in the PC accounts settings Family & other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a PowerShell issue and might be better suited for SuperUser. But I would guess that this is an issue with group membership. Unfortunately get-localuser doesn't give membership. So something like this would be the PowerShell way to check which user objects belong to which local groups.

```
Get-Localgroup | % { "`n$($_.name)`n"; get-localgroupmember $_}
```

Then check through which groups other user objects are a member of and add the KioskTest account to that group using this:

```
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "ExampleGroup" -Member "KioskTest"
```

Comment: I tried a couple of different ways of adding the local account and it seems to boil down to the lacking of membership through new-localuser. It's the best guess so far :-) I will talk to the program manager for Assigned Access and see what we can figure out! Thanks for taking the time to help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was a group membership issue. I have created some users with powershell new-localuser, but they did not show up in any GUI and I was unable to log on. The users were only visible in powershell with get-localuser and lusmgr. In settings, control panel 'user accounts' and login screen they did not show up.

I just had to add the new users to the local 'users' group. Once this was done, the new users were visible in all settings and available for login.
I was unaware of that local security policy (*local policy/user rights assignment/allow log on locally*) restricting login to '*Guest,Administrators,Users,Backup Operators*'.
Either add the users to one of these groups or add them to the local security policy.

Comment: `Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "users" -Member "MyUser"`

Answer (score 0):

To validate user is created or not, the below simple command helps. You may try it.

1. In case user is created you will get below output
   Command- net user TestUser2
   Output- 
   User name                    TestUser2
2. When user is not present
   Command- net user TestUser
   output-
   The user name could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was that when specifying the group I didn´t take into account that before the name of the group needs to go domain or in my case, name of the virtual machine. Therefore the command will look like this:
`... -Group "DomainName\ExampleGroup" ...`

You can check the existing groups on your machine by typing *lusrmgr* in Window´s *run* window.